# mail send format issue in different linux servers

Tags: linux, redhat, shell, sendmail

I have created a send mail script which will run on couple of my client servers. The mail was sent correctly in couple of servers but in some servers the format we receive is not what what we expected. What could be problem with wrong server and how to correct it so that it works correctly across all the servers?

### Mail script

```
    msg=$toaddr
    toaddr=$rtnaddr
    rtnaddr=$ccaddr
   echo "$msg" | mail -s "$subj" -c $ccaddr "$toaddr" -- -f "$rtnaddr"
```

### Works fine in this server

```
send_notification "Test" "this is test1" xxxx1@xxxx.com noreply@returnaddress xxxx2@xxxxx.com
email toaddress and cc with return address
[xxxx1]$ uname -a
Linux xxxx1 2.6.39-300.26.1.el5uek #1 SMP Thu Jan 3 18:31:38 PST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[xxxx1]$ rpm -qa |grep -i mail
sendmail-8.13.8-8.1.el5_7
procmail-3.22-17.1.0.1
mailcap-2.1.23-1.fc6
mailx-8.1.1-44.2.2
fetchmail-6.3.6-4.el5
```

Received email correctly

```
FROM: noreply@returnaddress
TO: xxxx1@xxxx.com 
CC: xxxx2@xxxxx.com
```

### In different server sends email and receive email in wrong format

```
[xxxx2]#  send_notification "Test" "this is test1" xxxx1@xxxx.com noreply@returnaddress xxxx2@xxxxx.com
email toaddress and cc with return address


[xxxx2]# uname -a
Linux xxxx2 3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 7 17:01:44 PST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[xxxx2]# rpm -qa |grep -i send
nautilus-sendto-2.28.2-4.el6.x86_64
[xxxx2]# rpm -qa |grep -i mail
procmail-3.22-25.1.el6.x86_64
mailx-12.4-7.el6.x86_64
perl-Mail-DKIM-0.37-2.el6.noarch
perl-MailTools-2.04-4.el6.noarch
mailcap-2.1.31-2.el6.noarch
libreport-plugin-mailx-2.0.9-19.0.1.el6.x86_64
```

Received mail as below

```
FROM: osuser@`hostname`
TO : noreply@returnaddress, -f@`hostname`, --@`hostname`, xxxx1@xxxx.com 
CC: xxxx2@xxxxx.com
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `mail` command called by `send_notification` is the same between the two servers? It appears from the message that it is not. You'll probably need to modify your script to account for the differences.

Comment: yes it is one script shared between all servers.

Comment: No, the command itself. As in `ls -lasH "$(which mail)"` or, probably even better, `ls -las "$(readlink -e "$(which mail)")"`